# Term for property of functions $f$ anf $g$ for which $f(g(x)) = x$

Tags: functions

I've just tried googling this extensively and I just can't seem to find the answer.

Let's say I have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(g(x)) = x$ and $g(f(y)) = y$, is there a name for this property? (Beyond $f$ is the inverse function of $g$?)

As a more concrete example I am thinking of encrypting/decrypting a value with some key:

$decrypt(encrypt(x, key), key) = x$

$encrypt(decrypt(y, key), key) = y$

"symmetric" was my first guess but as I understand it that applies to functions with the property $h(h(x)) = x$ and not two different functions.

Comment: This is the definition of inverse function, what else could you be looking for?

Comment: You evidently _know_ that this says $g$ is the inverse of $f$;  why do you want an answer "beyond" that? It's like you ask what the value of $2+2$ is, beyond $4$...

Comment: I was hoping for a single word to describe both functions (for a test case in my program) e.g. "test encrypt and decrypt are <property name here>" - I guess that "test encrypt and decrypt are invertible" would work? Just wondering if there is a more proper term to use

Comment: I would just say "invertible", like you did. It's the standard term, as far as I know.

Comment: I disagree—saying that two functions $f$ and $g$ are invertible does not imply that $g$ is the inverse of $f$ and vice versa. However, saying that they are *mutually inverse* or an *inverse pair* implies that both are invertible *and* each is the other's inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that $\{f,g\}$ form an *inverse pair*.

Answer (score 0):

The following statements about functions $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to X$ all mean the same thing:

- $g(f(x))=x$ and $f(g(y))=y$ for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$
- $f$ is an inverse for $g$
- $g$ is an inverse for $f$
- $f$ and $g$ are mutually inverse

Based on the comments under your question, it sounds like what you're looking for is the fourth option—that is, you could say something like *'test encrypt and decrypt are mutually inverse functions'*.